# Where can I find a library that parses source code and is able to extract the scope of where your cursor is currently in the code?

Tags: parsing, syntax-highlighting, textmate, sublimetext

In SublimeText(2), when you press [**ctrl + shift + p**] (mac osx) you are shown a scope of where your caret/cursor is in the source code at the given moment e.g.: `entity.name.tag.inline.any.html meta.tag.inline.any.html text.html.basic`

I am curious about what library or script is used to parse the document/file and create that scope string.

A sidenote: Typing `view.syntax_name(view.sel()[0].b)` into Sublime's console will output the scope as well.

Comment: "Programming documents"?  You mean HTML, or XML, or you mean source code for any programming language and the lexical block structure of each?

Comment: THANKS! I have been looking at that title for the past two days thinking to myself "that doesnt sound right".  Big time brain spasm.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "THANKS!" is for, I'm still unenlighted.  So... what do you mean?  If you think your question went off the rails, nobody will fault you for just deleting it.  If it didn't, you are welcome to edit it into a form where your question about the universe is crystal clear, even if the universe itself isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, the "libraries" that you are referring to are just the ***language grammars***.

Indeed, language grammars are just *rule sets for divindg a document's syntax into scopes*.

In other words, each rule in a grammar just assigns one or more elements of syntax to a scope.

w/r/t the the actual ***parsing***, for TextMate and Sublime Text, it is done by ***regular expressions***.

For instance, consider the python language grammar; As you know, when i put my cursor at the beginning of *while*, and do *ctrl-shift-P* (show scope), the scope will appear in the status bar:

```
source.python.keyword.control.flow.python
```

Again, this scope is defined in the python language grammar, so we can find the specific rule:

```
{ 
  match = '\b(elif|else|except|finally|for|if|try|while|with|break|continue|pass|raise|return|yield)\b';

  name = 'keyword.control.flow.python';
}
```

The first item, ***match*** is just the *pattern* that is passed into the parser.

The second item, ***name*** is just the name given to that particular syntax element (i.e., the *scope*).

**Sublime Text 2** stores language grammars in the *Packages* directory with the extension *tmLanguage* as XML rather than JSON, so the rule above from the python language grammar looks like this in ST2:

```
<dict>
    <key>
        match
    </key>
    <string>
        \b(elif|else|except|finally|for|if|try|while|with|break|....[truncated]
    </string>

    <key>
        name
    </key>
    <string>
        keyword.control.flow.python
    </string>
</dict>
```

So every rule in the grammar is *wrapped* in a pair of ***dict tags***, and each rule's *regexp* pattern is wrapped in ***string tags***; ditto for its corresponding scope name.

All of the language grammars are comprised entirely of these rules--with precisely this *match/name* (or *pattern/scope*) structure.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer - I was ignorant to the nomenclature "language grammars".  Is there anywhere available where I can find a "directory" of the regular expressions used to parse the source code or should I just be referencing *.tmLanguage files?

Comment: no problem. That's exactly right, so just choose the language of interest to you, e.g., python, find the correct ST2 file in the Packages directory, which has the extension *tmLanguage*. Those files are just a collection of two-item rules sets as i mentioned above. the "match" items of course are the actual regexp patterns. (Note that ST2 seems to store these files as XML rather than JSON--i'll update my answer given i was considering TM only when i wrote it.

Comment: I think the term "language grammar" is pretty abused here.  "Grammar" has a well defined meaning (look it up at Wikipedia).  Now that I understand what this editor does, I'm fine with the idea it uses a heuristic ("look for regex") to partition code into regions.  But that can't get lexical scopes *right*.... for that you need real parsing for most real languages, in which such scopes nest.

Comment: @IraBaxter You need to take that up with the TextMate developer. *Language Grammar* is the term the TM creator chose to refer to the mini-language that creates the "smart templates." It is a core feature of his editor and is mentioned extensively throughout his docs. See [LG](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#language_grammars). In other words, LG refers to an App *feature*; So when i wanted to refer to a feature of this App, i used the term given by the App's developer--i don't see a good reason to do otherwise